# using for loop unix shell in sqlplus

Tags: shell, sqlplus

I am trying to do the following:

```
sqlplus id/pw <<EOF
! for i in 1 2 3; do echo "$i"; done
EOF
```

but unfortunately I become an empty output

Can you give me solution to get the output 
1
2
3

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to run a unix loop in sqlplus

Comment: You cannot run a unix loop inside SQL*Plus, you can however run SQL*Plus inside a unix loop.

Comment: Though it would be useful to know what you're attempting to do, why do you need a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
for i in 1 2 3
do
    sqlplus id/pw <<< "$i"
done
```

?

Alternatively

```
printf '%s\n' "$i" | sqlplus id/pw
```

if you're not using Bash.

Comment: but that mean if I want to run the script 10 times I have also to login 10 times and this exactly I won't it. This way I am trying to run the loop inside the sqlplus.